# how to match two routes from Google Directions API response?

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I building an application that matches the route of a user with the routes of all others users. Routes of all users are collected using google directions api. i am not able to figure out a efficient solution to match the routes.
example: User 1 travels from A to B. User2 from L to M and User 3 from X to Y. Now, i have the direction responses from google map api(preferably json objects) which has latlng info of all the points in the three routes. Now i need to find if route A to B matches with other two routes either full or partially.[ By full,i mean that they have either same origin or destination and by partial, i mean if any two routes have some part common or atmost 2 kilometers part].

I can do this by comparing each point in route A to B with points in other routes.But this is a tedious task consuming all my resources and timetaking.
please help me with efficient solution.
I would be glad if there is any algorithm to simplify this task?

Answer (score 0):

> I can do this by comparing each point in route A to B with points in other routes.

This is just about the only way.

The only refinement is to [Simplify](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/) the lines first. This reduces the amount of points you have to compare.

Do beware of the Google Maps API terms, you can't take the data you obtain from the API outside of a Google Maps application. So you should be fine as long as you keep the data within a Maps API website, but dont export the data anywhere.